# How to get Thunderbolt 4 dock to work on Thunderbolt 3 port? (Dell Precision 5510)

Tags: ubuntu, hardware-failure, kali-linux, thunderbolt

I have a Dell Precision 5510 laptop with Thunderbolt. I'm able to get TB3 devices to connect in Windows and Linux without issue, but cannot get TB4 docks to connect. I've tried three brands (ACASIS, Satechi, Anker) and none work. At best, the Anker dock appears to connect and immediately disconnect every few seconds.

In Windows 10 (Intel i7-6820HQ CPU is not 'supported' by Win11) I've updated BIOS to 1.23.0, and updated TB firmware and drivers to latest available on Dell's support site. Event Viewer showed some NHI errors initially so I went so far as to install a clean Win10 instance on a new drive. Event Viewer shows successful setup of a TB3 device with the latest driver, Device Manager looks good (System Devices > Thunderbolt 1575 is present) but USB flash drives, Ethernet adapters, TB3 external drives all are not visible. Only one brand (Anker) produces the Windows sounds for device connected/disconnected, and Thunderbolt Control Center briefly flashes the device to authorize it; the other two brands make no sound and don't appear in TBCC.

In Linux (Ubuntu 22.04 and Kali Linux 6.5.0)...
**dmesg** shows:

```
[ 4458.751130] thunderbolt 0-1: new device found, vendor=0x1ca device=0x1
[ 4458.751146] thunderbolt 0-1: Satechi Thunderbolt 4 Dock
[ 4459.963355] thunderbolt 0-1: device disconnected
[ 4460.062609] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3hot to D0, device inaccessible
[ 4460.122000] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[ 4460.122031] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Controller not ready at resume -19
[ 4460.122033] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!
[ 4460.122035] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[ 4460.122078] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: remove, state 4
[ 4460.122081] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 4460.122284] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[ 4460.122291] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: remove, state 4
[ 4460.122294] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 4460.122607] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[ 4460.122611] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[ 4460.122809] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[ 4460.123553] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
[ 4460.123573] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: PCI bridge to [bus 06-3e]
[ 4460.123578] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x3fff]
[ 4460.123587] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
[ 4460.123594] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0xa1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 4464.007141] thunderbolt 0-1: new device found, vendor=0x1ca device=0x1
[ 4464.007157] thunderbolt 0-1: Satechi Thunderbolt 4 Dock
[ 4465.099481] thunderbolt 0-1: device disconnected
[ 4465.202935] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
[ 4465.202983] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: PCI bridge to [bus 06-3e]
[ 4465.202998] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x3fff]
[ 4465.203025] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   bridge window [mem 0xc4000000-0xda0fffff]
[ 4465.203044] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0xa1ffffff 64bit pref]
[ 4469.137613] thunderbolt 0-1: new device found, vendor=0x1ca device=0x1
[ 4469.137629] thunderbolt 0-1: Satechi Thunderbolt 4 Dock
[ 4470.235456] thunderbolt 0-1: device disconnected
```

**lshw** shows:

```
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #15
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.6
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:127 ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:c4000000-da0fffff ioport:80000000(size=570425344)
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcieport
                resources: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:c4000000-da0fffff ioport:80000000(size=570425344)
              *-pci:0
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                   version: 00
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:128 memory:da000000-da0fffff
                 *-generic
                      description: System peripheral
                      product: DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                      version: 00
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
                      resources: irq:18 memory:da000000-da03ffff memory:da040000-da040fff
              *-pci:1
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: pci@0000:07:01.0
                   version: 00
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:129 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:c4000000-d9efffff ioport:80000000(size=570425344)
              *-pci:2
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: pci@0000:07:02.0
                   version: 00
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:d9f00000-d9ffffff
                 *-usb
                      description: USB controller
                      product: DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:3e:00.0
                      version: 00
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                      resources: irq:163 memory:d9f00000-d9f0ffff
                    *-usbhost:0
                         product: xHCI Host Controller
                         vendor: Linux 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 xhci-hcd
                         physical id: 0
                         bus info: usb@3
                         logical name: usb3
                         version: 6.05
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usbhost:1
                         product: xHCI Host Controller
                         vendor: Linux 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 xhci-hcd
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: usb@4
                         logical name: usb4
                         version: 6.05
                         capabilities: usb-3.10
                         configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
```

**lspci -vt** shows:

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-01.0-[01]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M]
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
           +-16.3  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family KT Redirection
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
           +-1c.0-[02]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 8260
           +-1c.1-[03]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
           +-1d.0-[04]----00.0  Micron/Crucial Technology P5 Plus NVMe PCIe SSD
           +-1d.4-[05]--
           +-1d.6-[06-3e]----00.0-[07-3e]--+-00.0-[08]----00.0  Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
           |                               +-01.0-[09-3d]--
           |                               \-02.0-[3e]----00.0  Intel Corporation DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation CM236 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
```

0000:00:1d.6 appears to be the Thunderbolt controller address.
I've also tried manually forcing a removal and rescan of devices using:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:1d.6/remove > /dev/null

echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan > /dev/null
```

**Drivers** for nVidia and nouveau have been uninstalled or blacklisted to prevent power control conflicts.

**fwupdmgr** shows no available firmware updates.

**BIOS**
I've reset the BIOS by pulling the coin battery, but I did fail to turn off BIOS Recovery from Disk so it pulled the last BIOS backup off the M.2 drive. I'm willing to retry if anyone thinks it would help... any ideas which BIOS version to load? (I did have issues upgrading BIOS from I think version 1.18 or 1.19 where I had to downgrade in order to upgrade to latest.)

**thunderbolt-tools** and **bolt** packages are both installed. Thunderbolt security has been tried as 0 (none) and 1 (user level). BIOS > Thunderbolt > Pre-boot turned on and off; no difference.

I've tried the TB4 cables included with each dock as well as a short (5-inch) TB3 cable included with a Sabrent NVME external enclosure. Oddly, I get more activity with the TB3 cable, meaning the repeated "found"/"disconnected" loop whereas the TB4 cable does it a once or twice and then stops.

Anything else to try before I (sadly) pack these docks back up for return? I would really like to get ONE of these working.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dell TB4 docks do appear compatible per Dell's compatibility guide here - https://www.delltechnologies.com/asset/en-au/products/electronics-and-accessories/technical-support/dell_docking_compatibility_guide.pdf