# Thunderbolt Host Controller missing in Ubuntu... is that normal?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, firmware, thunderbolt, dell-precision

Is it OK to have Thunderbolt bridges, NHI, and PCI Express Root Ports but no "Thunderbolt Host Controller" using `lspci` on a TB3 capable system?

My Dell Precision 5510 (TB3 capable) laptop connects TB3 devices fine but won't connect TB4 devices. My Linux knowledge is limited but noticed in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS that "Thunderbolt Host Controller" doesn't show up anywhere in `lshw` or `lspci` output.

<Disclosure: I posted more details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1822299/how-to-get-thunderbolt-4-dock-to-work-on-thunderbolt-3-port-dell-precision-551).>

Using `lshw` and `lspci` it looks like the system has one of these two bridges:

```
DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
```

`lspci -t` at some point returned this:

```
+-1d.6-[06-3e]----00.0-[07-3e]--+-00.0-[08]----00.0  Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
           |                               +-01.0-[09-3d]----00.0-[0a-3d]--+-00.0-[0b]----00.0  ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
           |                               |                               \-01.0-[0c]----00.0  Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                               \-02.0-[3e]--
```

I would really appreciate any help diagnosing whether this is a config issue (firmware/drivers) or a hardware limitation/failure. At this point I've down & upgraded BIOS and firmware hoping something falls into place but two weeks of effort later, I haven't figured it out.